# Trouble parsing URLs from a list imported with pickle using newspaper library

Tags: python, pickle, python-newspaper

I've been trying to pass a list of urls to extract articles from the pages. Extraction(with newspaper) works just fine if I build an actual list of urls (e.g. lista = 'http://www.zeit.de', ...). Taking the list from another file does not work, however, even though printing the list works. The following is the code:

```
import io
import newspaper
from newspaper import Article
import pickle

lista = ['http://www.zeit.de',
         'http://www.guardian.co.uk',
         'http://www.zeit.de',
         'http://www.spiegel.de']

apple = 0
banana = lista[apple]
orange = "file_" + str(apple) + ".txt" 

while apple <4 :

   first_article = Article(url= banana , language='de')     
   first_article.download()    
   first_article.parse()

   print(first_article.text).encode('cp850', errors='replace')

   with io.open(orange, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
       f.write(first_article.text)

   apple += 1
   banana = lista[apple]
   orange = "file_" + str(apple) + ".txt"
```

The above MCVE works fine.  When I unpickle my list, printing it to console works as I expect, for example with this script:

```
import pickle
import io

lista = pickle.load( open( "save.p", "rb" ) )    
print lista
```

A sample of the List output looks like this

```
['www.zeit.de/1998/51/Psychokrieg_mit_Todesfolge', 'www.zeit.de/1998/51/Raffgierig', 'www.zeit.de/1998/51
/Runter_geht_es_schnell', 'www.zeit.de/1998/51/Runter_mit_den_Zinsen_', 'www.zeit.de/1998/51/SACHBUCH', 'www.zeit.de/199
8/51/Schwerer_Irrtum', 'www.zeit.de/1998/51/Silvester_mit_Geist', 'www.zeit.de/1998/51/Tannen_ohne_Nachwuchs', 'www.zeit
.de/1998/51/This_is_Mu_hen', 'www.zeit.de/1998/51/Tuechtig', 'www.zeit.de/1998/51/Ungelehrig']
```

but there are thousands of urls in the list.

The error message shown doesn't tell me much (full traceback below)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\newspaper\parsers.py", line 53, in fromstring
    cls.doc = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\lxml\html\__init__.py", line 706, in fromstring
    doc = document_fromstring(html, parser=parser, base_url=base_url, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\lxml\html\__init__.py", line 600, in document_fromstring
    value = etree.fromstring(html, parser, **kw)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3032, in lxml.etree.fromstring (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:68121)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1786, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:102470)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1667, in lxml.etree._parseDoc (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:101229)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1035, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseUnicodeDoc (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:96139)
  File "parser.pxi", line 582, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:91290)
  File "parser.pxi", line 683, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:92476)
  File "parser.pxi", line 633, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:91939)
XMLSyntaxError: None
```

I've been trying to fix this for hours but I just haven't found a way. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show the whole traceback.

Comment: You are aware that the line `print(first_article.text).encode('cp850', errors='replace')` is wrong, no? You are encoding the return value of the function `print` - why would you want to do that?

Comment: It seems to me that your description does not match your question title and the trouble is not with importing the pickled list.  If `lista = pickle.load( open( "save.p", "rb" ) )

print lista` gives the output you expect, then the pickle load has worked. it seems more likely there's a problem with what's actually in the list.  Can you give a bit more detail (e.g. two or three lines of output from the print lista after loading pickled list and the full traceback)?  Also consider changing the title of your question.

Comment: I've added the full traceback and a sample from the list. The encoding part  worked for printing german text in the console, so I'm reluctant to change that. Thanks for the quick answers, I'm really desperate.

Comment: It's the URL's in the list, not the pickling, that are the problem - see answer below.  At that point - it's not strictly a programming issue (we probably can't debug a library here).  There is probably non standards-compliant HTML in the page at the link you're pointing to (common in 1998  and still a problem today)

Comment: Actually - as you say you're desperate -  I've just looked and for the 1998 article, after download, there is no HTML in the article object.  OK - got it - you need to prepend http:// to all your URLs.  hang on a minute and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @fnl Interestingly, `print(first_article.html).encode('cp850', errors='replace')` works, I guess the print function's return value is the string it prints...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the object you're trying to pickle / unpickle is the list of URLs in the lista variable.  I'll make that assumption.  Therefore, if

```
lista = pickle.load( open( "save.p", "rb" ) ) 
print lista
```

gives the output you expect, then the pickle load has worked. it seems more likely there's a problem with what's actually in the list.

Having a quick look at the newspaper.py code on Github - we see that the error is thrown by this line:

```
 cls.doc = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
```

Looking at Article.parse() - that calls the Parser.fromstring() method - so it is a good bet that the problem here is that when you call first_article.parse().

That bit of code in the newspaper library carries the comment

```
 # Enclosed in a `try` to prevent bringing the entire library
 # down due to one article (out of potentially many in a `Source`)
```

So I think it's highly likely that it's a problem with one of the (first?) articles in your list imported from the pickle

***EDIT:***

following OP question edit - the problem with your code is the first URL in your list as suspected.  Try it manually in a console e.g.

```
url = 'www.zeit.de/1998/51/Psychokrieg_mit_Todesfolge'
first_article = Article(url, language='de')
first_article.download()
first_article.parse()
```

it gives the same (or similar) error.  However, if I try a different article - e.g. http://www.zeit.de/community/2015-01/suizid-tochter-entscheidung-akzeptieren, the above code works fine and I see the text if I type

```
print(first_article.text.encode('cp850', errors='replace'))
```

So, it's the contents that are at fault, not the pickle.  For some reason, the lxml library and newspaper library cannot parse that article.  I can't say why, it looks OK when I go to it in a browser.

***EDIT2:***

following comment discussion with OP - the problem is that the URLs in the unpickled list start `www.` rather than `http:\\www.`.  To solve that

```
url = ''
lista = pickle.load( open( "save.p", "rb" ) )

for u in lista:
    if u.startswith('www'):
        url = 'http://' + u
    else:
        url = u

# Carry on with your url processing here
```

Comment: Now it's working just fine. Thanks a lot for helping, such a stupid mistake. I'm sorry for stealing everyone's time.

Comment: No problem - they all feel stupid once you've found them